# Creating associated model with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, model-associations

I am trying to create associated models with Rails. My models are Financial which have many documents and Document which belongs to Financial. A working code when creating the associated model could be

```
def create
  @financial = Financial.find(2)
  @document = @financial.documents.create(document_params)
  ...
end
```

In my view I have a form which looks like this to select the right Financial

```
<%= form_for Document.new do |f| %>
<%= f.collection_select :financial_id, Financial.all, :id, :description %>
<%= f.submit %>
```

I do see the right parameters being transferred in the log when I submit the form

```
"financial_id"=>"3"
```

So I figured I would just need to change the initial code to:

```
def create
  @financial = Financial.find(params[:financial_id])
  @document = @financial.documents.create(document_params)
  ...
end
```

but I get a "Couldn't find Financial with 'id'=". I have tried other things including:

```
  @financial = Financial.find_by(id: params[:financial_id])
```

Without much success. Could anyone give me the appropriate syntax please? Thanks.

Comment: can you put code for document_params ?

Comment: yeah, perhaps a [strong parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) issue? Have you permitted :financial_id on Document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Couldn't find Financial with 'id'=

Because, the `params` that are submitted are actually inside `document` hash. So `params[:financial_id]` won't work. Instead you need to use `params[:document][:financial_id]`

```
def create
  @financial = Financial.find(params[:dcument][:financial_id])
  @document = @financial.documents.create(document_params)
  ...
end
```